# How to include a java compile task in a custom plugin?

Tags: java, gradle

I would like to create a custom gradle plugin with a java compilation task. Here is my first shot:

```
class SpringDocPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task(type: JavaCompile, "generateSpringDoc") {
            source = it.sourceSets.main.java
            classpath = it.sourceSets.main.output + configurations.compile

            options.compilerArgs = [
                    "-proc:only",
                    "-processor", "com.thilko.springdoc.SpringAnnotationProcessor"
            ]
            // specify output of generated code
            destinationDir = it.sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
        }
    }
}
```

I have a test project where the plugin is applied. The plugin is found, but I get this error:

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle-springdoc-plugin-test'.
> Could not find property 'sourceSets' on task ':generateSpringDoc'.
```

I have no clue how to add specific tasks to my plugin, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sourceSets` is a concept/model (not task) introduced by the `java-base` plugin. Source set instances such as `sourceSets.main` are added by the `java` plugin (which builds on top of `java-base`). If your plugin deals with source sets, add the following at the beginning of its `apply` method:

```
project.plugins.apply("java") 
// or: project.plugins.apply(org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin)
```

Comment: Thx, found in an another plugin I also included a ```project.afterEvaluate```block. https://github.com/jamiefolson/JAnnotateR/blob/master/gradle-plugin-rjava/src/main/groovy/com/jfolson/gradle/jannotater/RJavaPlugin.groovy#L45